# Navegar em pastas e subpastas com o powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

Recentemente fiz uma recuperação dos dados de um HD, porém a pasta onde os arquivos estão, está separada por subpastas com o nome de cada extensão (ex.: jpg, gif...), e cada subpasta contem outras subpastas separando os arquivos em "pequenas" quantidades (ex.: png[11001-12000]).

Queria montar um script em powershell pra poder copiar apenas os arquivos maiores que 100 KB, por exemplo, para outra pasta. Fazendo algumas pesquisas, achei um script que faz algo parecido

```
foreach($file in (Get-Item C:\Users\MEU_USUÁRIO\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets\*))
{
    if ((Get-Item $file).length -lt 100kb) { continue }
    Copy-Item $file.FullName "C:\Users\MEU_USUÁRIO\Pictures\PASTA_QUALQUER\$($file.Name).jpg";
}
```

Ele copia aquelas imagens do windows spotlight pra poder colocar de plano de fundo, porém não chega perto do que to precisando justamente por não navegar nas subpastas e tal. Não tenho nenhum conhecimento de powershell, e preciso da ajuda de vocês pra resolver esse probleminha, e de quebra aprender um pouco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de pesquisar e estudar um pouco, escrevi o seguinte código:

```
foreach($arq in (Get-ChildItem "DIRETORIO_DE_ORIGEM" -Recurse -Include "*.png", "*.gif", "*.bmp", "*.tif", "*.jpg"))
{
    if ((Get-Item $arq).Length -ge 200kb) {Copy-Item $arq.Fullname "DIRETORIO_DE_DESTINO\$($arq.Name)"}    
}
```

Ele copia os arquivos do DIRETORIO_DE_ORIGEM maiores ou iguais à 200kb para o DIRETORIO_DE_DESTINO. O que eu tive que mudar foi o nome das pastas que usavam caracteres que não eram permitidos (ex.: de "png **[** alguma_coisa **]**"para "png", ou "png(alguma_coisa)", por exemplo)

Pode-se usar o cmdlet `Move-Item` no lugar de `Copy-Item`, pra "recortar" o arquivo.